# Missing firestore documents

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a deployed Android application and one of my users has sent me screenshots showing entire sections of data missing. The missing data is contiguous. I can view the data within the app myself, but this user can not.

Has anyone seen this issue before? I'm using the RecyclerView adapter provided by the FirebaseUI library and a standard Firestore collection query with no limit and only one order by.

Edit:
It's a very simple query:

```
storageRef.collection(LOGS).orderBy("time", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);
```

Security rules certainly allow the person to view this data. It's just the query does not return all data. Initially they could view all documents and only recently noticed missing documents.

Comment: It's better to add some code how you retrieve data.

Comment: maybe your rules are not set up to everyone to read ?

Comment: Please add more code and the database structure.

Comment: I would first ask the user to delete their cache, and certainly check firebase rules, if there is anything that filters a view is either some code that checks the roles or within firestore rules.